# Как заставить работать пакет npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, frontend, npm

Новичок в npm, и появился вопрос, к примеру я установил Vue JS через npm, все нормально встало, в package.json Vue отобразился, но Vue код не работает, полез гуглить, установил browserify, в файле с js  написал `var _Vue = require('vue');` и изменил все `New Vue({})` на `New _Vue({})`. Потом ввел `browserify js/main.js -o js/main.vue.js -d`, подключил новый созданный файл, но все равно ничего не работает, в чем может быть проблема? Когда устанавливал таким способом jquery, то все работало

```
var _Vue = require('vue');
_Vue.component('assortment-card', {
    props: ['props'],
    template: `
        <div class="card" :class="{cardBottom: props.cardPositionBottom}">
            
        </div>
    `
});
let assortment = new _Vue({
    el: '#assortment',
    data: {
        cardInfo: [
            {
                cardId: '1',
                cardName: 'Lasagna',
                cardDesc : 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
                cardPrice: '200',
                cardImgSrc: 'img/shutterstock_91005374.png',
                cardImgSrcWebp: 'img/shutterstock_91005374.webp',
                cardPositionBottom: false,
            },
            {
                cardId: '2',
                cardName: 'pizza',
                cardDesc : 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
                cardPrice: '399',
                cardImgSrc: 'img/shutterstock_294636281.png',
                cardImgSrcWebp: 'img/shutterstock_294636281.webp',
                cardPositionBottom: false,
            },
            {
                cardId: '3',
                cardName: 'IDLIS',
                cardDesc : 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
                cardPrice: '99',
                cardImgSrc: 'img/shutterstock_139456373.png',
                cardImgSrcWebp: 'img/shutterstock_139456373.webp',
                cardPositionBottom: true,
            },
            {
                cardId: '4',
                cardName: 'BURGER',
                cardDesc : 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
                cardPrice: '129',
                cardImgSrc: 'img/shutterstock_361890518.png',
                cardImgSrcWebp: 'img/shutterstock_361890518.webp',
                cardPositionBottom: true,
            }
        ],
    },
});
```

Comment: Покажите код. Приложите фрагмент. Нам как вам помочь?

Comment: Так какой код показывать, я вроде все описал  кажется проблема в консоли а не в коде, кода там три строчки и я их написал в описании

Comment: Так вот приложите 3 строчки вашего кода main.js и ваши ожидания от него после применения команд npm install ,и прочих

Comment: Написал код в вопросе

Comment: Мои ожидания после установки npm чтобы начал работать Vue JS

Comment: `но Vue код не работает` - как Вы это установили? Какой командой запускали?

Comment: vue-cli установлен? покажите package